# Is the PyObject* returned by PyModule_Create 'borrowed' or 'acquired'?

Tags: c, python-3.x, python-c-api, reference-counting

The [latest Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_Create) only says this about `PyModule_Create`:

> The module initialization function may create and return the module object directly. This is referred to as “single-phase initialization”, and uses one of the following two module creation functions:
>
> `PyObject* PyModule_Create(PyModuleDef *def)`
>
> - Create a new module object, given the definition in *def*. This behaves like `PyModule_Create2()` with *module_api_version* set to `PYTHON_API_VERSION`.
> - ...
>
> Before it is returned from in the initialization function, the resulting module object is typically populated using functions like `PyModule_AddObject()`.

Also, `PyModule_Create` isn't on the list from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10247779/234175). This would suggest the conventional behavior is being followed, namely the caller is expected to 'acquire' the reference to `PyObject*` being returned.

But yet from this [python3porting](http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html#module-initialization) blog post, it has the following example:

```
static PyObject *
moduleinit(void)
{
  MOD_DEF(m, "themodulename",
          "This is the module docstring",
  module_methods)

  if (m == NULL)
      return NULL;

  if (PyModule_AddObject(m, "hookable",
         (PyObject *)&hookabletype) < 0)
      return NULL;                         /* line A */

  return m;
}
```

Would 'line A' not leak the reference for this code path? What is the proper usage and ownership semantics of `PyModule_Create`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code snippet simply isn't managing reference counts correctly. Aside from the leak you spotted, it also forgets to `Py_INCREF(&hookabletype)`, despite the fact that [`PyModule_AddObject` steals a reference to the value](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html#c.PyModule_AddObject).

As usual where not otherwise specified, `PyModule_Create` returns a new reference, not a borrowed reference.

Comment: okay, that makes sense. So in the event where you need to signal a module load error *but* `PyModule_Create` already succeeded, a `Py_DECREF(m)` is necessary?